# Answered with a link, now answer has been deleted, question closed as unspecific

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, link-only-answers

I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582631/a-class-with-only-functions/18582715#18582715) with a link, which has now been converted into a comment and the question itself closed.

From my perspective it was pretty simple - OP asked question, I answered, OP liked my answer and I was awarded the correct answer and some upvotes.

After that some other people came in, decided the question was 'unspecific' (even though I answered) and deleted my answer (even though it was liked and accepted).

Now I'm not exactly an old hand but this is the first time anything remotely like this has happened to me - and for something that seems fairly mundane and routine.

I'd like to know what I missed.

Comment: _"Since my comment appears to be the answer:"_ <--- this is a problem. Not the only one but please don't copy and paste a link as an answer.

Comment: What's wrong with taking a comment that's actually an answer and making it into an answer?  Futhermore what's wrong with copy-pasting a link into an answer... a lot of my answers (even high voted ones) have links in them.

Comment: Your highly voted answers have links _in_ them. The answer you provided once shorn of fluff was _just_ a link. Your highest voted answers look amazing and you seem to explain things in all of your answers. That's brilliant but just a link isn't necessarily.

Comment: Nothing wrong with taking a comment that's actually an answer and making it into an answer, or with using links into an answer. Link _only_ answers, on the other hand, are not really answers.

Comment: @NPSF3000 If it's a comment, it almost certainly isn't an answer.  It may be the base for which an answer can be built around, but it's almost certainly not an answer *yet* if it's posted as a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two completely seperate issues here, the deletion of your answer and the closing of your question.

> Why was my answer deleted?

This is the easy one.  It doesn't actually answer the question, given the requirements of an answer on this site.  Your answer is almost entirely an external link.  When writing an answer you should write it such that the reader doesn't *need* to follow any links.  It's great if they want to, but your answer should answer the question with every single link in the answer removed.  There are several reasons for this, discussed in several places on meta.  Some of the high points:

- Link rot; what happens when the target site shuts down?
- How do users know if they can trust links?
- It's rude.  We're looking to be a place where people can find answers, not places where the go to be linked to places that link to places that link to places that happen to be slightly related but don't actually answer the question, or if they do, require way more work for the reader than they should.

If you have an external resource that you feel answers the question you should quote/summarize enough of the resource (citing as appropriate) so that your post answers the question without needing to follow the link.

> Why was the question closed?

Because it's unclear what the person is asking for.  Even you didn't know.  You found something that you think might be related, or at least might be something that the OP can use to figure out the answer, but as it is, with the information in the question, those 5 users felt that it was impossible to answer the question.  If the OP is able to clarify their post (hopefully helped by people asking clarifying questions to direct them to the unclear points) the question should become clear enough to be reopened.